# how to get eth_signTypedDataV4 signature in web3.py

Tags: solidity, web3.py, python, signature, server-side

I am currently using web3.py on a backend, I want to generate eth_signTypedDataV4 signature with web3.py, I am using Infura as a provider. which web3 method is available or any other library, when it comes to javascript there is https://www.npmjs.com/package/eth-sig-util library, could not find simmilar library for python.

Answer (score 2):

EIP712 signatures can generated using the https://eth-account.readthedocs.io/en/stable/eth_account.html#eth_account.messages.encode_structured_data function to encode the EIP712 message, and use web3 to sign it.

```
    msg = { "types": 
    { "EIP712Domain": [], "Type":  []},
      "domain":domain,
      "primaryType": 'Type',
      "message":message }
```

`encoded_data=encode_structured_data(msg)`

`web3.eth.account.sign_message(encoded_data,privateKey)`